# RPATH and overlay filesystem

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, rpath

If I have an A.so file, and it requires B.so in runtime. If the RPATH of A.so is not set, I assume it will look for B.so under /lib/ during runtime.
In addition, if I also set up an overlay filesystem over /lib/ and there is another B.so (Let's call this one B'.so) on the upper directory. Which one of the B.so will A.so link to in runtime?
I assumed A.so will link to B'.so in runtime, but it seems that I was wrong after I made some experiments.

Comment: Could you specify which "experiments" you did exactly? Then maybe others can try to reproduce the behaviour you describe. Also, how is this behaviour related to RPATH, if it is not set?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do an example. We create directories with

```
$ mkdir upper
$ mkdir lower
$ mkdir merged
$ mkdir work
```

Then we write code

```
// libupper.c
#include <stdio.h>
void print_hello(void) {
    printf("hello from upper\n");
}

// liblower.c
#include <stdio.h>
void print_hello(void) {
    printf("hello from lower\n");
}

// main.c
void print_hello(void);
int main(void) {
    print_hello();
}
```

Compile it with

```
$ gcc --shared -o lower/lib.so liblower.c
$ gcc --shared -o upper/lib.so libupper.c
```

Mount the overlay

```
$ sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o "upperdir=upper,lowerdir=lower,workdir=work" merged
```

Compile the main program

```
$ gcc -o main main.c merged/lib.so
```

And run it

```
$ ./main
```

will print

```
hello from upper
```

So as you assumed, the library from the upper directory is called as it shadows the lower one.

**BIG FAT NOTE** I can only guess what your "experiments" looked like, because you did not provide any further information, but I guess you produced some undefined behaviour by modifying the underlying filesystems, which is explicitly prohibited for overlay filesystems (see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html#changes-to-underlying-filesystems)). While the overlay fs is mounted, you **should not** make changes in the `upper` or `lower` directories, but only in the `merged` directory.